# Azure function app deployment working with VS 2017 but not with Azure Web App deploy task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-functions-runtime

I have release azure function app from **VSO Azure App Service Deploy release task**, 
it gives:
**System.Nets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions** I searched on google, people say the sockets get expired but i am using S3 pricing tier

I have then released the same function app from Visual Studio 2017 which runs perfectly fine without any exceptions.

I am attaching the artifacts, build assets, release pipeline details, please help. I will not be able to move to production unless this issue is resolved.

[Structure of Artifacts which is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN9Tb.png)

[Structure of artifacts which is working fine-published from VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0B8Z.png)

Here is the github link for more details regarding the issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11345

Comment: Are you publishing these to the same app? I see this error when I try to access a resource behind a VNet when my function app isn't joined to the VNet. Is it possible that's the case here?

Comment: This error message relevant with Socket, but not only socket is expired. You can refer to this doc: [Local Address Requests](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#local-address-requests).

Comment: @jeffhollan yeah i am publishing to the same app, i can see the app settings getting changed every time i give a fresh release with changed app settings. That can be a possibility. But this problem has got solved when i changed my storage account to point to a different one. But still i am not sure what was wrong with the newly created Storage account.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that it helps the wider community

Comment: Sorry for the late reply the problem got solved, by changing UseDevelopmentStorage=true to point to exact storage account address.

Answer (score 0):

I had to give a proper storage connection string for the following, instead of UseDevelopmentStorage=true,

Comment: And what would be the proper storage connection string?

Comment: When you create a function app, it has a storage account linked to it, we should use that one here.